# UIImage imageNamed does not display the image with xcode 4.4

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode4.4

I've been stuck with adding a UIImage to my iPhone application, to add an image i usually used the name of the image and put it like that : 
`UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];`

But in my application i don't know the name of the image when i'm writting the code, i've got the image name with a webservice and i put it in a NSString.

So i have a string `m_image1`, and i want to display the image in a UIImage like that :

```
UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:m_image1];
```

But nothing appears on the screen, when i use `NSLog` to show if `m_image1` has the right string it works, and when i paste what is print in the log in the imageNamed it works.

I've already tried using the path of my application, but nothing do it ! So i don't know what to try anymore !

That's my all block of code :

```
NSLog(@"m_image1 : %@",m_image1); 
UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:m_image1]; 
m_result1ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage1]; 
m_result1ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 163.f, 260.f); 
[m_ScrollImages addSubview:m_result1ImageView];
```

Everything work just fine, when i put :

`UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];`

instead of :

```
UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:m_image1];
```

it display the image !

Comment: that line of code only **loads** image, it does not **displays** it on the screen...

Comment: I use a UIImageView right after that 'm_result1ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage1]' but it doesn't display the image anyway !

Comment: ok, do you **add** that imageView to some view? :)

Comment: Here's my entire block of code : 
NSLog(@"m_image1 : %@",m_image1);
UIImage* myImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:m_image1];
m_result1ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage1];
m_result1ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 163.f, 260.f);
[m_ScrollImages addSubview:m_result1ImageView];

So yes it's the same view !

Comment: add code to your initial question, it is too hard to read it in comments. What is m_ScrollImages and is everything ok with it?

Comment: What do you get if you log [m_image1 class]?  Does it give you NSString?

Comment: It says `__NSCFString` in the log !

Comment: Do you think that's why it doesn't work ? How can i convert it to NSString ?

Comment: NSCFString is just a constant string, that will work fine, if its actually the value you need.  imageNamed: doesnt care whether the string passed in is a variable or a constant.  In your code you never show the assignment to m_image1.  If the value was what you expected the image would be loaded.

Comment: Well the weird thing is that in my log, m_image1 is equal to `myimage.png` and when i write `imageNamed:@"myimage.png"` then it works, so m_image1 gets the right value but doesn't allow me to display the picture

Answer (score 4):

I think your image is not in the resources!

Check your image: Go to the `Project Navigator` and click on blue icon which is your project. Now in `Targets` click on your target and go to `Build phases` tab and check `Copy bundle resources`.

Your image file must be in the list, if it is not add it and check the program again!

I hope it be useful for you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I checked on my copy bundle ressources and the images are in the list ! But the thing is that when i replace `m_image1` which is the string that contains the name of the image to display by the actual name of the image `@"myImage1"` then it works, the image is displayed !

Answer (score 1):

try this code ,

```
m_result1ImageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: m_image1]]];
```

Comment: Still doesn't show anything, but thx for your answer ! It doesn't matter where i put my images in the application folder ? Because even if i get the name of the image to display with a webservice i have all my images in my application folder, i'm just getting the name from my webservice and put it in m_image1 !

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not copied exactly the images in your application bundle that is being not displayed .

Try & check removing bunch of images and add those again in your project.